# The child object is not saved without any errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Ruby version                   2.4.5-p335 (2018-10-18) [x86_64-linux]
Rails version                  5.2.2

```
class TemplateCategory < ActiveRecord::Base    
    #self.table_name = "rt_template_categories"
    has_many :templates, dependent: :delete_all    
    validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2 }
end
```

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
    #self.table_name = "rt_templates"
    belongs_to :template_category
    validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 12 }
end
```

```
class TemplatesController < ApplicationController
    def create

      @template_category = TemplateCategory.find(params[:template_category_id])        
      @template = @template_category.templates.create(template_params)

      #@template_category.templates << Template.create

      #@template = Template.new(body:"qqq qqq qqq", template_category_id: "4")
      #@template.save

      #sql = "INSERT INTO redmine.templates (template_category_id, body) VALUES('#{params[:template_category_id]}','#{params[:template][:body]}');"
      #records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)  
    
      redirect_to controller: "template_categories", action: "show", id: @template_category.id
    end
    
    private
      def template_params
        params.require(:template).permit(:body)
      end
end
```

very simple classes, very simple controller, no errors in the log, but the object is not saved. I've tried different options, but they all don't work, except for directly executing the SQL query.

Comment: Try adding a `!` after `create` and see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

`length: { minimum: 12 }` - here's the reason!
I completely forgot about this restriction when I was testing the work.